# Using NSAppleEventsUsageDescription in Xamarin to get Login Items

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, applescript

I need to run AppleScript from my code to get LoginItems name. I am able to do it from Xcode project.  But when I do same with Xamarin it fails.

What am I missing in Xamarin project? Any help to get the login Items will be appreciated.

**Xcode Project code:**

```
NSString *script = @"tell application \"System Events\" to get the path of every login item";

NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];

NSDictionary* errorDict;

NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [appleScript executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
```

**Xcode Project plist Value:**
[image]
The last value:

I do the similar in Xamarin:

```
var script = "tell application \"System Events\" to get the path of every login item";
var appleScript = new NSAppleScript(script);
var descriptor = appleScript.ExecuteAndReturnError(out var errorInfo);
```

The info.plist

[image]

The Xamarin `errorInfo` value I get is :

```
{{
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "System Events";
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1743";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {44, 4}";
}}
```

But it should not happen as I am added the `Privacy` part in the plist.

Comment: What is the actual NSError returned?

Comment: @SushiHangover: I added it in the question, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting that error message/number and having the proper Info.plist entry:

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>StackOverflow needs access to your System Events </string>
```

**Note**: You should double-check the `Info.plist` file via an edit editor vs. the VS IDE to ensure that the `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key is properly defined as shown above.

Means you are **not** getting the Security popup to grant permission.

[image]

Which means that the user has denied permission access when originally asked.

Open:

```
System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Privacy Tab / Automation
```

Find your app the list and grant it permissions manually:

[image]

Note: I use AppleScript|JavaScript all the time for macOS automation via Xamarin.Mac so I know Xamarin is not the problem. If it turns out that it is not the Automation permission getting originally denied, I would like to hear the about the problem as this is the only one issue I have ever seen (all my code, 5+ years, check for that error and directs to the user to manually correct the issue since they denied access the first time it was asked).

Comment: But I don't want this to do manually. If that was the case, I shouldn't have added the `Privacy-` in the plist. I want to achieve it through my app. The Xcode project does it, why the VS project fails, is my concern.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The first time, you should get security prompt to grant or deny, IF you deny, it will never prompt again, not a Xamarin problem, that is the way macOS works (same as iOS, ask once for permission, never ask again).

Comment: But I never get for this VS project. :(

Comment: Then double check your Info.plist with `vi` (or some text editor, not the Xamarin IDE), BUT did you check to see if the app is registered in the Automation list with System Events denied??? Change the bundle id and re-run the app, I bet it prompts you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added from Xamarin IDE, and the Key value was not the same as it is in Xcode. Now it works. Add the above as *answer*.